# Slow SQL Code on local server in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a particular SQL statement which takes about 30 seconds to perform, and I'm wondering if anyone can see a problem with it, or where I need additional indexing.

The code is on a subform in Access, which shows results dependent on the content of five fields in the master form. There are nearly 5000 records in the table that's being queried. The Access project is stored and run from a terminal server session on the actual SQL server, so I don't think it's a network issue, and there's another form which is very similar that uses the same type of querying...

Thanks

PG

```
SELECT TabDrawer.DrawerName, TabDrawer.DrawerSortCode, TabDrawer.DrawerAccountNo, TabDrawer.DrawerPostCode, QryAllTransactons.TPCChequeNumber, tabdrawer.drawerref
FROM TabDrawer LEFT JOIN QryAllTransactons ON  TabDrawer.DrawerRef=QryAllTransactons.tpcdrawer
WHERE (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName Is Null 
      Or [drawername] Like Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName & "*") 
      And (Forms!FrmSearchCompany.SearchPostcode Is Null 
      Or [Drawerpostcode] Like Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchpostcode & "*") 
      And (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchSortCode Is Null 
      Or [drawersortcode] Like Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchsortcode & "*") 
      And (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount Is Null 
      Or [draweraccountno] Like Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount & "*") 
      And (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque Is Null 
      Or [tpcchequenumber] Like Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque & "*");
    ");
```

---

**EDIT**

The Hold up seems to be in the union query that forms the QryAllTransactons query.

```
SELECT 
  "TPC" AS Type, 
  TabTPC.TPCRef, 
  TabTPC.TPCBranch, 
  TabTPC.TPCDate, 
  TabTPC.TPCChequeNumber, 
  TabTPC.TPCChequeValue, 
  TabTPC.TPCFee, 
  TabTPC.TPCAction,
  TabTPC.TPCMember, 
  tabtpc.tpcdrawer,
  TabTPC.TPCUser,
  TabTPC.TPCDiscount,
  tabcustomers.*
FROM 
  TabTPC 
  INNER JOIN TabCustomers ON TabTPC.TPCMember = TabCustomers.CustomerID

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
 "CTP" AS Type, 
  TabCTP.CTPRef, 
  TabCTP.CTPBranch, 
  TabCTP.CTPDate, 
  TabCTP.CTPChequeNumb, 
  TabCTP.CTPAmount, 
  TabCTP.CTPFee, 
  TabCTP.CTPAction,
  TabCTP.CTPMember,
  0 as CTPXXX,
  TabCTP.CTPUser,
  TabCTP.CTPDiscount, 
  TABCUSTOMERS.*
FROM 
  TabCTP  
  INNER JOIN TabCustomers ON Tabctp.ctpMember = TabCustomers.CustomerID;
```

I've done a fair bit of work with simple union queries, but never had this before...

Comment: You say "Access project." Is this an ADP? If so, that definitely changes the kinds of answers you need.

Comment: I've read through the entire thread and I still don't know if it's an ADP->SQL Server or an MDB->ODBC->SQL Server.

Comment: please to be answering david's question immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. Since this is an Access database with a SQL Server backend, you may find a considerable speed improvement by converting this to a stored proc.

Second, do you really need to return all those fields, especially in the tabCustomers table? Never return more fields than you actually intend to use and you will improve performance.

Comment: This hit the nail on the head - There is a report that needs all the fields, but for this particular case, the left join didn't even need to be there - I've created a watch that creates the union rather than a stored proc, and it's sped things up at least 50 fold. Thanks to all for their help :)

Comment: How about defining your form controls as parameters in the first SQL statement? I don't use ADPs, but with MDBs or ODBC->SQL Server it speeds things up. It can completely change what Jet passes off to SQL Server in the latter case, and I'd think an ADP would be equally smart (if not smarter).

Answer (score 1):

At first, try compacting and repairing the .mdb file.

Then, simplify your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
  [drawername] Like Nz(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName, "") & "*"
  And 
  [Drawerpostcode] Like Nz(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchpostcode, "") & "*"
  And 
  [drawersortcode] Like Nz(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchsortcode, "") & "*"
  And 
  [draweraccountno] Like Nz(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount, "") & "*"
  And 
  [tpcchequenumber] Like Nz(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque, "") & "*"
```

Does it still run slowly?

**EDIT**

As it turned out, the question was not clear in that it is an up-sized Access Database with an SQL Server back end-and an Access Project front-end.

This sheds a different light on the whole problem.

Can you explain in more detail *how* this whole query is intended to be used?

If you use it to populate the RecordSource of some Form or Report, I think you will be able to refactor the whole thing like this:

- make a view on the SQL server that returns the right data
- query that view with a SQL server syntax, not with Access syntax
- let the server sort it out

Comment: He's using an access project file which is essentially just the frontend (GUI and some VBA) to the data stored in SQL Server, so there's no MDB and no reparing needed.

Comment: Another point to mention is that with your suggestion the query should be even slower because the costly part is the like operator and now you're doing it, even if the value was null.

Comment: Really, does he? I've found out about that several hours ago. Discussion went on in the comments to his answer. Until there was a chance to find the problem I did not see reason to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are in QryAllTransactons?

If your result returns 0 rows then Access may be able to see that immediately and stop, but if it returns even a single row then it needs to pull in the entire resultset of QryAllTransactons so that it can do the join internally. That would be my first guess as to what is happening.

Your best bet it usually to do joins on SQL Server. Try creating a view that does the LEFT OUTER JOIN and query against that.

Your goal, even when Access is running on the SQL Server itself and minimizes network traffic, is to only send to Access what it absolutely needs. Otherwise a large table will still take up memory, etc.

Comment: I've just checked, there's 166 rows on that query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running each of the subqueries in the union? Usually optimizers don't spend much time trying to inspect efficiencies between union elements - each one runs on its own merits.

Given that fact, you could also put the "IF" logic into the procedural code and run each of the tests in some likely order of discovery, without significant additional overhead from more calls.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of those like operators.

In your case you don't need them. Just check if the field starts with a given value which you can achive whith something like this:

```
Left([field], Len(value)) = value
```

This method applied to your query would look like this (did some reformatting for better readability):

```
SELECT
  TabDrawer.DrawerName, 
  TabDrawer.DrawerSortCode, 
  TabDrawer.DrawerAccountNo, 
  TabDrawer.DrawerPostCode, 
  QryAllTransactons.TPCChequeNumber, 
  TabDrawer.DrawerRef
FROM
  TabDrawer 
  LEFT JOIN QryAllTransactons 
    ON TabDrawer.DrawerRef = QryAllTransactons.TpcDrawer
WHERE 
  (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName Is Null 
  Or Left([drawername], Len(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName)) = Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchName)
And
  (Forms!FrmSearchCompany.SearchPostcode Is Null 
  Or Left([Drawerpostcode], Len(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchpostcode)) = Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchpostcode) 
And 
  (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!SearchSortCode Is Null 
  Or Left([drawersortcode], Len(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchsortcode)) = Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchsortcode) 
And 
  (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount Is Null 
  Or Left([draweraccountno], Len(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount)) = Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchaccount) 
And 
  (Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque Is Null 
  Or Left([tpcchequenumber], Len(Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque)) = Forms!FrmSearchCompany!Searchcheque)
```

Note that you're comparing case sensitive. I'm not totally sure if the like operator in MS-Access is case insensitive. Convert both strings to upper- or lowercase, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you upsized did you make sure the tables were properly indexed? Indexes will speed queries tremendously if used properly (note they may also slow down inserts/updates/deletes, so choose carefully what to index)